# How do I inherit a qweb report template and replace a t element in odoo

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-13

I want to replace the t element and every data under it in my payslip qweb report.
That is the t element and everything that comes under it

```
<t t-call="web.internal_layout">
   <div class="page">
       <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
        ............
       </table>
     </div>
</t>
```

I have tried

```
  <template id="report_payslip_inherit_logo" inherit_id="hr_payroll.report_payslip">
            
    <xpath expr="//t[1]" position="replace">
    </xpath>
```

But it gives an error that  is not located in the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly give the `XPath` to the `t-call` like this.
Code:

```
<xpath expr="//t[@t-call='web.internal_layout']" position="replace">
    <!-- Your Code -->
</xpath>
```